# How do I pull values from a radio button with a label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In regards to question [getting the text of radio button instead of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365853/getting-the-text-of-radio-button-instead-of-values), How do I pull values from a radio button with a label?

I did not post this question there, I fealt it did not go with the original question.

How would you then get the value of the selected radio? I have tried both `$("input[type='radio'][id='rblUnitOfMeasureType']:checked").val()` and `$("input[type='radio'][id='rblUnitOfMeasureType']:checked + label").val()`, they both return undefined.

I am using a form, but the form is just there as a from tag, the rest of the html is basically a formless form (if that makes sense).

```js
 function listUnitOfMeasureSet_change() {
   if (listUnitOfMeasureSet.value.toString().toLowerCase() === "new") {
     $("#divNewTypeUnitContentHolder").html("");

     callService("GET", g_WebServiceUnitsOfMeasureTypeUnitsURL, null, function(jsonResult) {
       if (jsonResult.Success) {
         for (i = 0; i < jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureTypeList.length; i++) {
           $("#divNewTypeUnitContentHolder").html($("#divNewTypeUnitContentHolder").html() +
             '<input type="radio" id="rblUnitOfMeasureType' + i + '" name="rblUnitOfMeasureType" value="' +
             jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureTypeList[i].ID + '" /><label for="rblUnitOfMeasureType' + i + '">' +
             jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureTypeList[i].Name + '</label> ' +
             jsonResult.UnitOfMeasureTypeList[i].Description + '<br />');
         }
       }
     });

     $("#divNewUnitOfMeasure").dialog("open");
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have that on jsfiddle by any chance?

Comment: Can we at least see your HTML please

Comment: I over looked the id being an increment so I had to use Name instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one should work, another option is to use `.attr('value')`

```js
$('input').click(function(){
    console.log($("input[type='radio'][id*='rblUnitOfMeasureType']:checked").val());
    console.log($("input[type='radio'][id*='rblUnitOfMeasureType']:checked").attr('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' id='rblUnitOfMeasureType' value='15'>
<input type='radio' id='rblUnitOfMeasureType4' value='17'>
```

Comment: Cannot use ID, because of the increment, however name works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

if you check for the one that is checked first and then if you use that selector with:

```
("#input_test").attr('text')
```

it returns the text inside the radio input.

Answer (score 0):

On `radio` select trigger a function and capture it's detail as below:

```
$("input:radio[name=radios]").click(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    alert($(this).parent().next().find('label').text());
});
```

**Reference html:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="radio1" name="radios" type="radio" value="radio 1"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="radio1">
          check radio 1
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <input id="radio2" name="radios" type="radio" value="radio 2"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label for="radio2">
          check radio 2
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArpitAggarwal/Lt9tpp79/) for the same.